# Jenkins Workflow: Unable to implement trait in Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

#### Setup

Let's assume I have the following configuration on my Jenkins Shared Library:

```
vars/
   utils.groovy
src/
   com.my.corp.utils/
      tools/
         Utilities.groovy
      helpers/
         Workflow.groovy
```

##### Workflow.groovy

```
package com.my.corp.utils.helpers
// import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript

trait Workflow
{
    def workflow
}
```

##### Utitities.groovy

```
package com.my.corp.utils.tools
import com.my.corp.utils.helpers.Workflow
// import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript

class Utilities implements Serializable, Workflow
{
    def x = 5
    def y = 10
    
    def echo(Map args)
    {
        this.workflow.sh """echo 'args: ${args}'"""
        this.workflow.sh """echo 'args.inspect(): ${args.inspect()}'"""
        this.workflow.sh """echo 'this.steps: ${this.workflow}'"""
        
        this.workflow.echo message: args.inspect()
        this.workflow.sh """echo "${this.workflow.class.getName()}; args: ${args}\""""
    }
}
```

##### utils.groovy

```
import com.my.corp.utils.tools.Utilities

def call(Map params)
{
    this.echo "${this}"
    params.put('workflow', this)
    new Utilities(params).echo(params)
}
```

#### The Problem

When, in the main pipeline, I call `utils x: 1, y: 2`,
the following error appears:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed
```

##### Full Trace

*Long Java stacktrace warning!*

```js
14:56:21  org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
14:56:21  file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sandbox-Pipeline/builds/74/libs/245eaa38d10b90e40a75ee9676c50aa097d56330cf312d54476ed05f2c731cfa/src/com/my/corp/utils/tools/Utilities.groovy: -1: Unsupported array expression for CPS transformation in this context @ line -1, column -1.
14:56:21  file:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sandbox-Pipeline/builds/74/libs/245eaa38d10b90e40a75ee9676c50aa097d56330cf312d54476ed05f2c731cfa/src/com/my/corp/utils/tools/Utilities.groovy: -1: Unsupported array expression for CPS transformation in this context @ line -1, column -1.
14:56:21  2 errors
14:56:21  
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:786)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:743)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:812)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$TimingLoader.loadClass(CpsGroovyShell.java:170)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:702)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:812)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:800)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.global.UserDefinedGlobalVariable.getValue(UserDefinedGlobalVariable.java:52)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:115)
14:56:21    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7858.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:56:21    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
14:56:21    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
14:56:21    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
14:56:21    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:158)
14:56:21    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
14:56:21    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
14:56:21    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
14:56:21    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
14:56:21    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
14:56:21    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:18)
14:56:21    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
14:56:21    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor741.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:56:21    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
14:56:21    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor744.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:56:21    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
14:56:21    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
14:56:21    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
14:56:21    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
14:56:21    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
14:56:21    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
14:56:21    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
14:56:21    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

#### However

However, if I change the `Workflow` to be an `abstract class` instead of `trait`, and use `extends Workflow implements Serializible` instead of `implements Workflow, Serializible` in the `Utilities` definition, everything works fine!

Furthermore, when I run the code above (with traits) in [Groovy online executor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php), it works well too.

Comment: Why is `Workflow` necessary here? Everything looks fine in general otherwise, which seems to concur with your observed behavior when you modify `Utilities`.

Comment: I tried to set up the generic implementation for all classes those act like scripts (`Script`) which would nest a more-generic trait that allows interacting with Jenkins (`Workflow`)

(There would be other implementations for these traits/ABCs)

Comment: That sounds rather ambitious and interesting. All I can really say is good luck and hopefully one of the JP lib super-experts can figure this one out with you.

Comment: The best thing I have got up with is to forget about half-working groovy runtime sandbox-proxy-wrapper-compiler and instead create a pipeline-compatible plugin on Java or Scala.